# Clarification for a loop to create interaction terms in Stata

Tags: loops, stata, interaction

I found the following question/answer that I think does what I would like to do: https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-09/msg00449.html

However, I am unclear what is going on in all of it, and would like to understand better. The code for the solution is as follows:

```
unab vars : var1-var30
local nvar : word count `vars'
forval i = 1/`nvar' {
  forval j = 1/`=`i'-1' {
    local x : word `i' of `vars'
    local y : word `j' of `vars'
    generate `x'X`y' = `x' * `y'
  }
}
```

I do not understand what is going on in line 4 with the statement: ``=`i'-1'`.

The i refers to the number in the set {1,...,n}, but I do not understand what the equals or the -1 are doing. My assumption is that the -1 is somehow removing the own observation, but I am unclear. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing to do with observations, which are not even mentioned here. The outer loop is over the set of all variables and the inner loop is over one fewer. In pseudocode `j` runs from `1` to `i - 1`. See `help macro` for the syntax.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do? The `=`i'-1' statement is Stata macro syntax. The = sign within macro quotes tells Stata to evaluate the expression, so this evaluates to `i' - 1 each loop. However, as Nick says, this is nothing to do with observations, so perhaps you haven't quite found your solution? This creates all pairwise interactions (except own interactions, i.e. squares) of  set of variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I had not run across an = sign within a macro before, and this is helpful. To make sure I understand what is going on, I can nest a macro or variable (i in this case) inside macro quotes with an equal sign to evaluate it, and this can be done anytime I want to evaluate an expression that includes a macro. So the following would be equivalent:
1/`i' or 1/`=`i'' and both would generate interactions including quadratic terms.
A related question: is there a similar way to reference a scalar in an expression? Or do I need to store it as a macro to evaluate an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have local macro `i` that varies over a range and you want its value minus 1. You can always do this

```
  local j = `i' - 1
```

and then refer to `j`. You can also do this on the fly:

```
 `= `i' - 1'
```

Within

```
 `=   '
```

Stata will evaluate the expression, here

```
`i' - 1
```

and substitute the result of that expression in a command line.

You can do this with scalars too:

```
scalar foo = 42
```

and then refer to

```
`= foo'
```

However, watch out. Scalar names and variable names occupy the same namespace.

```
`= scalar(foo)'
```

disambiguates and arguably is good style in any case.